# How to run commands without sudo on Ubuntu startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a below command which I have to run manually each time whenever the `Ubuntu` machine starts or reboots.

```
ngrok start --all
```

This command can only be run without `sudo`. If I run it as `sudo ngrok start --all`, it gives error. Due to this I am not able to create script which I can run as `systemd` service, so that the service automatically starts on every boot and executes the script and the command starts.

I have also tried `crontab` by adding below line to `sudo crontab -e` but it also didn't worked.

```
@reboot ngrok start --all
```

How can I run above command without `sudo` on startup of Ubuntu. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: Just use `crontab -e` without the `sudo`?

Comment: @muru Let me try it now.

Comment: @muru its not working with `crontab -e` without sudo

Comment: @muru When I run `ngrok start --all`, it loads up my portal. But using it in crontab, portal is not loading.

Comment: @muru It starts my website `www.mywebsite.com`. I can open it in my browser.

Comment: Then try with `ngrok start --all 2>&1 > /tmp/ngrok.log` and check what error you get in `/tmp/ngrok.log`.

Comment: @muru  file is created as `/tmp/ngrok.log` but there is nothing in it

Comment: Ah, sorry, it should be `> /tmp/ngrok.log 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that time, it already runs with root privileges, so there is no need to use `sudo`. Just run it without it.

You only need `sudo` when you are logged in, and a program runs using your user account with less privileges; `sudo` gives such a program root privileges. Processes started during system startup or in (root's) crontab already run as root.

There is even a solution how to run this as a systemd unit:

https://github.com/vincenthsu/systemd-ngrok

Comment: I didn't get you, can you explain a bit more

Comment: So you mean, we can not run commands without sudo at startup.? There is no solution for it or am I missing something?

Comment: You are thinking too complicated. `sudo` runs a program as root. At boot time EVERYTHING already runs as root. Just put that plain command into a systemd unit; there is no need for `sudo`.

Comment: I don't think it will run as systemd service. but let me try it once more.

Comment: I just added the URL of a systemd unit that does this to my answer above.

Comment: I will try the systemd service you mentioned in url and will update

Comment: @S Andrew it will run in `systemd` I would even go one step further and call `contab` legacy.

Comment: Using old crontab is not going one step further, it's putting more skeletons into that old musty closet. Use today's technology, i.e. systemd!

Comment: @SAndrew: So, what's the result? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Using `@reboot` in your `crontab` is the way to go, but there is something you should know about jobs run through `cron`:

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.